# .NET MVC bundle & minificafication issue

Tags: css, .net, model-view-controller

i have a project, i tries to bundle the CSS, like this

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/adminLteCss").Include(
                      "a.css",
                      "b.css"              
                      ));
```

i am expected rendered view is the same as

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="a">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="b">
```

except it bundles 2 css into a minified css [i have enabled the BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true]

but the result that they rendered the view differently (a font-family in the body didn't appended).

what is the reason of the cause?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying the font-family isn't being applied or that none of your stylesheets are rendering?

Comment: no,in fact i am not sure if there is any css not rendered after the bundle is added in the view. the main problem is that the rendered view is not the same as the view which directly appended 2 css

Comment: Ah okay, apologies, a little bit of lost in translation there :) If you open the Dev Tools in your browser and reload the page, you can check inside the bundle when the page loads to see if there is any content there at all to check that the bundle is actually being created

Comment: yes, it is created, also the CSS style is included (in chrome dev tools), but the view isn't rendered that

Comment: Only other thing I could suggest is in the past I have seen cases where the CSS causes conflicts with itself, namely one style overriding the another which could be what you're seeing?